# How to assign sequential identities to binary states with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to analyze some information about an object as it moves between three possible states. The data is laid out such that each state has its own column, with binary values in sequential order, e.g.,

```r
df <- data.frame(state1 = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0), state2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0), state3 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1))

print(df)

   state1 state2 state3
1       0      1      0
2       0      1      0
3       0      1      0
4       1      0      0
5       1      0      0
6       0      1      0
7       0      1      0
8       1      0      0
9       0      1      0
10      0      0      1
11      0      0      1
```

I would like to add a fourth column indicating the state being occupied, but while preserving sequence, e.g.,

```r
df2 <- data.frame(state1 = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0), state2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0), state3 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1), state.id = c(2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.2, 2.2, 1.2, 2.3, 3.1, 3.1))

print(df2)

   state1 state2 state3 state.id
1       0      1      0      2.1
2       0      1      0      2.1
3       0      1      0      2.1
4       1      0      0      1.1
5       1      0      0      1.1
6       0      1      0      2.2
7       0      1      0      2.2
8       1      0      0      1.2
9       0      1      0      2.3
10      0      0      1      3.1
11      0      0      1      3.1
```

How could I go about doing this (preferably via the dplyr package)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `max.col` to get maximum number in each row (`temp`). We also create a new column with `row_number()`, create a sequential counter within each `temp` which increments if the difference in row number is greater than 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   mutate(temp = max.col(.), 
          row = row_number()) %>%
   group_by(temp) %>%
   mutate(temp1 = cumsum(row - lag(row, default = first(row)) > 1) + 1,
          state.id = paste(temp, temp1, sep = ".")) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-temp, -temp1, -row)

# A tibble: 11 x 4
#   state1 state2 state3 state.id
#    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>   
# 1      0      1      0 2.1     
# 2      0      1      0 2.1     
# 3      0      1      0 2.1     
# 4      1      0      0 1.1     
# 5      1      0      0 1.1     
# 6      0      1      0 2.2     
# 7      0      1      0 2.2     
# 8      1      0      0 1.2     
# 9      0      1      0 2.3     
#10      0      0      1 3.1     
#11      0      0      1 3.1
```

Comment: Hey this was working great until for a few days but I've run into an issue since while re-running the code (including the reproducible example above). It seems the ```row_number()``` function is not working correctly anymore, and is seeking an argument. The error message I'm getting is: ```df %>%
+     mutate(temp = max.col(.), 
+            row = row_number())
Error: row_number() should only be called in a data context```

Comment: It seems like in the past other people have had an issue with R attempting to call ```dplyr::row_number()``` instead of the base version (the former requiring an argument, the latter not) -- https://community.rstudio.com/t/dplyr-row-number-v-s-row-number/6745/2 .  Might this be related?

Comment: @comcco It still works for me though. What version of `dplyr`, you are using? I have `packageVersion("dplyr") #[1] ‘0.8.1’`.

Comment: I have 0.8.3. I’m still looking into the issue, but it keeps demanding an argument - I’m also trying to figure out how to provide it the component of the temp row that would be necessary to create the counter

Comment: now I am using 0.8.1 and am still running into the same issue

Comment: @comcco Have you loaded `plyr` along with `dplyr` ? `plyr` also has `mutate` which might be getting masked here. Can you mention `dplyr::mutate` explicitly everywhere wherever you are using `mutate` and then check the results.

Comment: that seemed to do the trick! I also had `ggbiplot` loaded, which apparently also loads `plyr`, after I had already loaded `dplyr`, which seemed to do exactly what you suggested in breaking `mutate`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit complicated because you want to do two things and combine them:

1. Which state is active in a given row?
2. How many times has each state now been active?
3. (combine) how many times has the active state been active?

I think the way to do this in the end is to reshape the data, and use two groupings to get what you want:

1. Group by row and use `which` to figure out the state number that is active
2. Group by state, and use `cumsum` to get an index that goes up every time a state becomes active.
3. Then combining, `filter` to keep only the rows that correspond to the relevant column for each `rowid`, and `right_join` back onto the original data.

The second task in particular I think is hard to achieve without reshaping or dealing with an unwieldy number of columns.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(state1 = c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0), state2 = c(1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0), state3 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1))
df <- rowid_to_column(df)

df %>%
  gather(state, binary, -rowid) %>%
  arrange(state, rowid) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  mutate(state_num = which(binary == 1)) %>%
  group_by(state) %>%
  mutate(
    state_col_num = str_remove(state, "state") %>% as.integer(),
    sequence = cumsum(binary == 1 & lag(binary, default = 0) == 0)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(state_num == state_col_num) %>%
  unite("state.id", state_num, sequence, sep = ".") %>%
  right_join(df, by = "rowid") %>%
  select(rowid, matches("state(\\d+|\\.id)"))
#> # A tibble: 11 x 5
#>    rowid state.id state1 state2 state3
#>    <int> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1 2.1           0      1      0
#>  2     2 2.1           0      1      0
#>  3     3 2.1           0      1      0
#>  4     4 1.1           1      0      0
#>  5     5 1.1           1      0      0
#>  6     6 2.2           0      1      0
#>  7     7 2.2           0      1      0
#>  8     8 1.2           1      0      0
#>  9     9 2.3           0      1      0
#> 10    10 3.1           0      0      1
#> 11    11 3.1           0      0      1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>